# UIPageViewController cancel page swipe

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController with 7 pages. The user must enter all the required fields in each page before going to the next page. If the user doesn't enter a required field i should display a warning popup and keep the user in the same page if he tries to go to the next page. Does anyone know how i can cancel page swipe and keep the user in the same page if the user doesn't enter a required field?

Thanks,
Anand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a datasource for the pageviewcontroller, you can return nil for the method:

```
    - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

You are probably setting all viewcontrollers from start, but to do this you will need to set the initial viewcontroller, and provide the next and previous viewcontrollers from the datasource methods.

It will not disable the scrolling in the scrollview, meaning the user can scroll and 'bounce' against last page.

EDIT:
Please note that UIPageViewController does cache answers from it's datasource; When you return an answer for a given index, it will not ask for it again till scroll goes sufficiently far or you manually set the viewControllers.

For your refresh to work, as a workaround, you could call:

```
pageViewcontroller setViewControllers:[pageViewcontroller viewControllers]                                     direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                       animated:NO
                                     completion:nil];
```

to make it drop the caches and request the controller from your datasource again. (Thanks Douglas Hill)

Comment: If you change your return values to the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` methods, the `UIPageViewController` will not automatically call these methods again. There is no standard way to notify it of your changes — analogous to `UITableView`’s `reloadData`. A workaround to force reloading is to set the `UIPageViewController`’s view controllers to their current value: `[pageViewController setViewControllers:[pageViewController viewControllers] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil]`. It doesn’t matter what direction you specify.

Comment: @DouglasHill You are correct, when you want to refresh the page controller programatically that is what you need to do. I understand from the question that user changes page manually. So not returning a controller till the data is complete is perfectly feasible, and no refresh is needed. When user will swipe after data is complete next controller will be returned.

Comment: Did you try it? I did, and the page view controller keeps track of the last values provided by the data source. Say you’re on a page and at first there’s no next page, then something happens (the form is filled in) and there becomes a next page; scrolling still bounces, because the page view controller does not know about the page you just added. It must be told to reload from its data source.

Comment: @DouglasHill I tried it now in a demo project and it doesn't work. My answer is not correct. UIPageViewController seems to cache the responses from the datasource, and it doesn't ask it again till the viewcontrollers are set again. So the solution would be to return nil or the viewcontroller in the datasource, AND also to force the refresh as you mentioned.

Comment: I tired to return nil but it didn't work. After i set it to nil i entered all the required data and i tried to swipe again to the next page but the pageviewcontroller didn't load the next page as it already cached the next page to be nil.

Comment: @AnandY Edited answer by adding what Douglas Hill suggested.

Comment: @DarthMike Thank you so much. I tried your edited answer and it is working now. Thank you Douglas.